# How to insert an object from canvas?

Tags: android, performance

Is it possible to point image through canvas?. I am able to draw rect or draw line using canvas to my bitmap. but the thing is to insert image from drawable folder instead of pointing out rect or circle. is this possible to do. I am new to this topic, if anything wrong kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below

In your onDraw()

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage);
    // get bitmap from drawable folder
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, paint);
    // draw bitmap to canvas
```

1st argument is the bitmap, 2nd argument is the position to the left, 3rd argument is the position to the top and 4th argument is the paint object.

For more info check the doc

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `canvas.drawBitmap(yourBitmapInstace, 0, 0, null)`

1. first argument is the bitmap you want to draw
2. second argument is the position of the left side of the bitmap being drawn
3. thrid argument is the position of the top side of the bitmap being drawn
4. last is a paint instance and could be null

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bmpFactory= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, paint);
// draw bitmap to canvas
```

This will help you

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I used the same code to get my answer